# How to add a single image background to UiTableview Header and also its rows?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios8

I am aware of adding image as background to Tableview header and also its rows, but I am facing problem in adding a single image as background to section header and also its following rows.

I tried in may ways but didn't get a proper solution.I know we can do it using scrollview but it will become complex as the number of sections and rows increases.

[image]

In the above image, India is header and hyderabad etc are the cities related to that header.Check only single background image added here. If any one had done this kind of design, please share your suggestions or ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it a expandable tableview ?

Comment: yes,its expandble @Mr.T

Comment: ahh, that makes sense now!!!

Comment: is there any image behind the India ?

Comment: yes, we have image to section, as it expands the image also gets expand

Comment: When you reload your table data model, you could add/remove/update a UIImageView to the tableview main view for each section. Give the image view constraints to pin the leading and trailing to the edge and the top to an offset for the section. Do not pin the bottom, but give it a height constraint instead. When the table asks for a cell or header, set the constraints for the section image to the rectangle the section takes up. You can ask the table to tell you this size. This seems OTT doing it every cell request, but you have to allow for order being cells first when scrolling. Might work.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, USA and India are actually UITableViewCells with a lot of subviews.